# How to define a "image/jpeg" response in RAML?

Tags: rest, api, raml

I'm defining an API using RAML and I need return an image content (not as a JSON). Any special hint how to expose the method "content" in my API?

```
/images/{imageId}: 
  get: 
    responses: 
      200: 
        body: 
          application/json: 

... 
/images/{imageId}/content:
```

Answer (score 2):

For RAML 1 you can use the [file type](https://github.com/raml-org/raml-spec/blob/master/versions/raml-10/raml-10.md/#file), e.g.:

```
...
types:
  userPicture:
    type: file
    fileTypes: ['image/jpeg']
    maxLength: 307200

...
/images/{imageId}: 
  get: 
    responses: 
      200: 
        body: 
          image/jpeg: 
            type: userPicture
```

[For RAML 0.8 the file type is only aplicable to formParameters.](https://github.com/raml-org/raml-spec/blob/master/versions/raml-08/raml-08.md#type)

But you still can use the media type, e.g.:

```
/images/{imageId}: 
  get: 
    responses: 
      200: 
        body: 
          image/jpeg: 
            description: an image...
```

Comment: I tried this code but it's for the RAML 1.0, I'm using the 0.8 version. the way I made work was not mentioning the userPicture type

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I did :)